# Where is UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

Where/how do you call the SDK equivalent of `UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(...)` in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be this one:

MonoTouch.UIKit.UIVideo.SaveToPhotosAlbum

public static void SaveToPhotosAlbum (string path, MonoTouch.UIKit.UIVideo.SaveStatus status)

source: http://docs.go-mono.com/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIVideo/Members